# How to change Jackson to detect all fields in a POJO, other than only public ones?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, gson, jackson2

When using Spring Boot for a project, Jackson came as default to serialize objects back and from Jsons. I realize that Jackson fails if you don't have public accessors, e.g., getters/setters, or public fields in your POJO.

The behavior is different when I switch to Gson. It detects all fields regardless of their visibility. For this reason, I ended up using Gson.

I felt a little uncomfortable about switching my POJO access rules; It would force some refactoring in the project structure.

So, no problems using Gson, but is there a way of change Jackson's behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jackson does support reading values from private member fields, but does not do it by default.

You can configure the behavior globally in the Spring Boot config like

```
jackson:
  visibility.field: any
  visibility.getter: none
  visibility.setter: none
  visibility.is-getter: none
```

(this config will only look for member fields and no longer check get, set and is methods)

You could also use the @JsonAutoDetect annotation to do the same setting for a specific class.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had found the annotation solution in this [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-auto-detect.html). Still, your Spring Boot config alternative seems even better. I only need to change the behavior in only one place, instead of spreading annotations all over.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set visibility at ObjectMapper level,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
```